# Filter table based on row condition

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

I need a measure in DAX to filter based on the "Type", B value is prioritized against A

```
M   Type    QTY
Jan A   1
Feb A   2
Mar A   3
Apr A   4
Apr B   5
May A   6
May B   7
Jun A   8
Jun B   9
```

The DAX measure should return

```
Forecast(Jan)=1
Forecast(Feb)=2
Forecast(mar)=3
Forecast(Apr)=5
Forecast(May)=7
Forecast(Jun)=9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this calculated **Table** or just it's **Forecast** measure:

```
Table = 
VAR Forecast = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('Table'[QTY]),
        'Table'[Type] = MAX('Table'[Type])
    )
RETURN
    SUMMARIZE(
        'Table',
        'Table'[M],
        "Forecast", Forecast
    )
```

[image]